# How can I find check the coverage of changed code?

Tags: bash, jenkins, phpunit, code-coverage, git-diff

I have a Jenkins job that runs multiple jobs, some of those are unit tests for a different part of our platform.
One of those jobs is phpunitTest which basically makes sure that all tests are passing and generates a code-coverage using `Codecept`.

**My question now is, how can I make sure new code pushed is covered by the unit tests?**

Currently I'm using this command to run the coverage: 
`codeception/codeception run unit --coverage-html --quiet`

*I expect to see have a failed test if the code pushed isn't unit tested.*

Answer (score 1):

Unless Codecept has special (and unusual) tooling for this there's basically two ways: achieve 100% coverage and verify that at every run or force a move towards 100% coverage. Since most projects don't even go for 100% coverage (which is not at all the same as having covered all your bases; see for example [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/testing.html) for why 100% is just the beginning) I'll assume the latter. What you can do in that situation is to

1. enforce that the coverage percentage minimum is met at every CI run and
2. enforce that the coverage percentage is never lowered.

By these simple expedients you'll naturally ensure that code coverage goes up with every piece of code added.

This does not guarantee that each new piece of code is 100% covered; for that you would have to parse the coverage checker results and see if any new or changed files are mentioned as missing coverage.

Comment: interesting points, even though I didn't get a clear answer. but, still, that confirms to me that only way is to parse the output and compare with an older value.